# What is the typical process with filegroups in chirpy

Tags: javascript, jquery, chirpy

I have a filegroup configured with Chirpy:

```
<FileGroup Name="1.min.js" Minify="False">
    <File Path="test/temp1.js" />
    <File Path="test/temp2.js" />
  </FileGroup>
```

Now I set my master page to download this script `1.min.js`. So far so good but the problem is when I edit some of the script in `temp1.js`, I have to come in this mash.chirp.config and save this file too for 1.min.js to take updated changes from `temp1.js`. This is tedious for me. If I forget to save at both place it causes countless minutes to figure out why is it not worknig. Is there any better approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain and have had the same issues.  Basically, the way I resolved this is to just tell the page to load the JS file directly.  This seems to also play well with the js debugger because the files haven't been minified to a single line.

Then after the js file is complete, I add it to my mash.js.chirp.config file to be combined and minified.  I know it's not the answer you were hoping for, but despite having to process it in this manor during development, the payout in the end feels worth it to me.

If you really wanted to force it, you could add code to the web projects properties, in the after build command line to invoke the chirpy console to compile this file.  I've used the code for this before, but couldn't find it right now.  Some info is [here though](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/discussions/232543);  Oh and I wouldn't name your file .min.js unless you set minify = true.  It could come back to bite you later on if you forget you did that.

I found the link to force the compiler;
http://www.annhoang.net/twitter-bootstrap-in-visual-studio-2010-with-chirpy-and-dotless/